# AVAudioPlayer doesn't play audio in once in 15 times

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio, avaudioplayer

I'm facing a really strange issue with AVAudioPlayer. I have initialised the AVAudioPlayer as given below. 
It plays audio most of the time, but no audio plays once every 15-20 times. The player is getting initialised properly and there are no error.
Please help me fix the issue.

```
AVAudioPlayer *backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];
self.backgroundMusicPlayer = backgroundMusicPlayer;
[backgroundMusicPlayer release];
[self.backgroundMusicPlayer setDelegate:self];
[self.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.backgroundMusicPlayer play];
```

Comment: show your code of URl & getting data of audio file

Comment: if u r not using GCD then see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use `GCD to load audio data`. using GCD to asynchronously load the
>   song's data into an instance of NSData and use that as a feed to 
>   audio player. you have to do this because loading the data of an audio
>   file, depending on the length of the audio file, can take a long time
>   and if you are doing this on the main thread, then you are running the
>   risk of stalling the UI experience. Because of this, you have to use
>   global concurrent queue to ensure that your code does not run on the
>   main thread.if it is on the main thread then problem like you are
>   facing happens.
>   see this sample code

```
     dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, ^(void)
     { 
    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        NSString *filePath = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"MySong" ofType:@"mp3"];
        NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; NSError *audioPlayerError = nil;
     self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:fileData error:&audioPlayerError];

        if (self.audioPlayer != nil)
    {
        self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;
        if ([self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay] && [self.audioPlayer play])
    {
        NSLog(@"Successfully started playing.");
        } 
    else 
    { 
    NSLog(@"Failed to play the audio file.");
     self.audioPlayer = nil;
        }
        } 
    else { NSLog(@"Could not instantiate the audio player.");
} });
```

your problem also may be happen because of `initWithContentsOfURL`, if it not gets data through that URL then it not plays audio.

Other issue with your code is may be   releasing the audioPlayer object. If you are  allocating a lot of objects and never releasing them from memory. That could eventually lead to a low memory .

Comment: Thanks Ravindra, the issue which i'm facing is ("- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag") is getting called. But audio actually is not playing.

Comment: and more over i found that sometimes the audio plays distorted.

Comment: I tried using your code. But still I faced the issue. Still audio gets distroted at sometime.